# Quasar Upgrade issue

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

Is there any single command to replace the old quasar tags by the new ones ?
They have replaced the quasar tags for the latest versions.
Since I have upgraded to Quasar beta version, now I have to change the syntax of all my pages manually because of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to migrate automatically tags, CSS Classes, directives, etc...

But they provide an [upgrade guide](https://quasar.dev/start/upgrade-guide#Upgrading-from-0.x-to-v1) to assist in this task

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, you need to change them manually.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to upgrade quasar automatically.

Just use find and replace method and check how much UI break and then manually resolve it.